# Data still syncing with separate apple IDs

Tags: icloud, apple-id

So I moved to college and decided it was time for me to make my own apple ID. Up to that point I shared an account with my mother. Since updating my phone all of her contacts are on my phone. I created a new apple Id to keep all of our content separated. I now have a mac and want to use the cloud to get data from my phone but do not want to share everything with my mom. Everything on my phone that requires apple ID has only my account not hers. Help?

Comment: If contacts are still actively syncing then check "Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars".  There are actually quite a few places in settings that require update (logout old/login new) when you are separating AppleIds, it not just "Settings > iCloud"

Answer (score -1):

If I get what you mean, you would probably like [Family Sharing](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201088). It allows you to share data with another Apple ID, but keep thing separate (e.g your mom can download iTunes things from your account and you can download things from her account, but she can't read your iMessage and you can't read hers).